# С помощью чего лучше создавать landingpage?

Tags: html

Сейчас стоит задача создать толковую продающую страницу, дизайнерских познаний нет вообще, поэтому однозначно будет использоваться готовый шаблон. Есть вариант или воспользоваться сервисом http://q-page.ru/ (очень уж мне понравился у них темный шаблон) или сделать почти тоже самое на joomla (понимание этой ЦМС - чуть ниже среднего).

Что посоветуете?

Comment: с помощью HTML

Answer (score 1):

Landing page - рекламная \ завлекательная страница, которая, как правило, несет некую информацию, которая, по логике, должна завлекать покупателя \ посетителя и т.д.

CMS для таких целей бессмысленна.

Ставьте простой одностраничник, и отдельно кладите скрипт, который там сабскрайбить или еще что делать будет, по вашему желанию.

Answer (score 0):

http://q-page.ru/ - очень крутой сервис. Быстрый и удобный. Рекомендую.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать на чистом html\css\js. Был опыт, когда на огромный лендинг (такие, как простыня), заходило по 5к уников в день, и sweb, на самом дорогом тарифном плане ругался на большое использование серверного времени.

Хотя, оптимизировано было все что угодно. 
С CMS все было бы куда печальнее.

Как уже сказал Виталий, СMS для лендинга - бессмысленна.